# Laravel collection group by two columns

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array of openning/closing hours of a store :

```
array:3 [▼
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "opens_at" => "10:00"
    "closes_at" => "18:00"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "opens_at" => "10:00"
    "closes_at" => "18:00"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "opens_at" => "10:00"
    "closes_at" => "18:00"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "opens_at" => "14:00"
    "closes_at" => "17:00"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [▼
    "opens_at" => "14:00"
    "closes_at" => "17:00"
  ]
  6 => array:2 [▼
    "opens_at" => "18:00"
    "closes_at" => "19:00"
  ]
]
```

the keys of the array here from 1 to 6 are the days (Monday to Saturday) in this case, and I'm using a simple Enum class for this :

```
class WeekDays
{
    const MONDAY = 1;
    const TUESDAY = 2;
    const WEDNESDAY = 3;
    const THURSDAY = 4;
    const FRIDAY = 5;
    const SATURDAY = 6;
    const SUNDAY = 7;
}
```

So, I need to get a result that is grouping the days having similar openning & closing hours as follow :

```
[
    Mo,Tu,We 10:00-18:00,
    Th,Fr 14:00-17:00
    Sa 18:00-19:00
]
```

I can't figure out how to group by `opens_at` & `closes_at` to get any formatted result as I showed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a very elegant solution but it could give you a hint on how you can solve it yourself:

```
<?php

$a = [
  1 => [
    "opens_at" => "10:00",
    "closes_at" => "18:00"
  ],
  2 => [
    "opens_at" => "10:00",
    "closes_at" => "18:00"
  ],
  3 => [
    "opens_at" => "10:00",
    "closes_at" => "18:00"
  ],
  4 => [
    "opens_at" => "14:00",
    "closes_at" => "17:00"
  ],
  5 => [
    "opens_at" => "14:00",
    "closes_at" => "17:00"
  ],
  6 => [
    "opens_at" => "18:00",
    "closes_at" => "19:00"
  ]
];

$groups = [];

foreach($a as $dayNumber => $w){
    if(!array_key_exists($w['opens_at'] . '-' . $w['closes_at'], $groups)){
        $groups[$w['opens_at'] . '-' . $w['closes_at']] = [];
    }

    $groups[$w['opens_at'] . '-' . $w['closes_at']][] = $dayNumber;
}

$res = array_map(function($v){
    return implode(', ', $v);
}, $groups);

var_dump(array_flip($res));
```

Results in:

```
array(3) { ["1, 2, 3"]=> string(11) "10:00-18:00" ["4, 5"]=> string(11) "14:00-17:00" [6]=> string(11) "18:00-19:00" }
```

https://3v4l.org/p4oa6